# How do I change $(Version) macro in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros, version

I have a Visual Studio C++ Win32 Console application project. In the properties of the project I have set a Preprocessor definition VERSION=$(Version) and currently I use this macro in the code. The only problem is that the $(Version) appears to resolve to 1.0.0.0. I have searched the web and the project properties but I couldn't find the appropriate way to set this via the IDE. Also I tried to set the Linker-Version property but it didn't help as the $(Version) still 1.0.0.0.

Comment: Look to me you stumbled into something undocumented.  Not sure where that macro comes from, it *looks* like a clumsily named property used for ClickOnce, it stores the intermediate assembly manifest version.  Nothing to do with C++, best forget it exists.

Comment: I tend to agree -- I've also been searching for $(Version), couldn't find it anywhere!